# azure User assigned managed identify not showing up in the list

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I created a user assigned managed identity and added the Managed Identity Operator role - and it is listed under Managed Identities menu. However, when i go to my vm and try to add the 'User assigned' managed identity, nothing shows up in the dropdown for 'User assigned managed identities'. Both the identity and the VM are in US east.

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the VM and recreated it, and now the ID is visible in the dropdown list. Not sure what the issue earlier was.